# Assign Column name to first column R table

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I want to save the following table out of **R**:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
z <- rnorm(100)
model <- z ~ x + y
results <- glm(model)
pe <- results$coefficients
vc <- vcov(results)
se <- sqrt(diag(vc))
results.table <- round(cbind(pe, se),3)
rownames(results.table) <- c("Intercept", "X-Estimate", "Y-Estimate")
colnames(results.table) <- c("Parameter", "pe", "Se")
write.table(results.table,file="test.csv",row.names=T,col.names=NA,sep=",")
```

However, I am unable to provide a column name for the rownames:

```
colnames(results.table) <- c("pe", "Se")     # works
colnames(results.table) <- c("Param", "pe", "Se")    # Doesn't work, incorrect length
```

UPDATE:  ANSWER

According to a comment, this is impossible.  Here is a roundabout way of doing this, if you are interested:

```
rows <- c("Intercept", "X-Estimate", "Y-Estimate")
results.table <- round(cbind(pe, se),3)
results.table <- cbind(rows,results.table)
colnames(results.table) <- c("Parameter", "pe", "Se")
write.table(results.table,file="test.csv",row.names=F,sep=",",quote=F)
```

Comment: Row names are attributes of the matrix, rather than values existing in matrix elements. They are not in a "column" that can be named.

Comment: So I guess this is impossible, and should just cbind the rownames and give them a column name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit shorter than what you suggested in your question's "UPDATE" would be:

```
write.csv(cbind(Parameter = rownames(results.table), results.table),
          file = "test.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```